# How do I call an MvxCommand/ICommand when selecting an item from a Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am enjoying the N+1DaysOfMVVMCross but I am stuck on Day 5 (Sort of a day 2 and day 5 combo)...

I used day 2 to develop a grid view UI and wanted to use the day 5 info to add a Command that will open a secondary view when an item is selected from the grid.  The Command code in the ViewModel is never executed (though it does execute from a button).

I think the issue is more related to WPF/XAML but thought I would reference MVVMCross as this is where I hit the road block.

Thanks for any help/tips/direction

How about some source code...

From the view model, sorry for the list initialization I'm slowly working through this.

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TeleBacteriology.Core.Services;

namespace TeleBacteriology.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class WorklistViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public WorklistViewModel(IWorklistItemService service)
        {
            var newList = new List<WorklistItem>();

            WorklistItem newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250001", "http://placekitten.com/301/301");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250002", "http://placekitten.com/302/302");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250003", "http://placekitten.com/303/303");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250004", "http://placekitten.com/304/304");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250005", "http://placekitten.com/305/305");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250006", "http://placekitten.com/306/306");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250007", "http://placekitten.com/307/307");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250008", "http://placekitten.com/308/308");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250009", "http://placekitten.com/309/309");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            newWorklistItem = service.CreateNewWorklistItem("201401250010", "http://placekitten.com/310/310");
            newList.Add(newWorklistItem);

            Worklist = newList;
        }

        private List<WorklistItem> _worklist;
        public List<WorklistItem> Worklist
        {
            get { return _worklist; }
            set { _worklist = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Worklist); }
        }

        private MvxCommand _detailsCommand;
        public System.Windows.Input.ICommand DetailsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _detailsCommand = _detailsCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoDetailsCommand);
                return _detailsCommand;
            }
        }

        private void DoDetailsCommand()
        {
            ShowViewModel<PlateDetailsViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML for the view:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="TeleBacteriology.Store.Views.WorklistView"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TeleBacteriology.Store.Views"
    xmlns:common="using:TeleBacteriology.Store.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>

        <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="itemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Worklist}"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Worklist250x250ItemTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccessionNum}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageUrl}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Worklist80ItemTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="6">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="60" Height="60">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AccessionNum}" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" MaxHeight="40"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageUrl}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
        <x:String x:Key="AppName">My Application</x:String>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid used in most view states -->
        <GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Padding="116,136,116,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Worklist250x250ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            SelectedItem="{Binding DetailsCommand}"/>

        <!-- Vertical scrolling list only used when snapped -->
        <ListView
            x:Name="itemListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Margin="0,-10,0,0"
            Padding="10,0,0,60"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding DetailsCommand}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Worklist80ItemTemplate}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"/>

        <!-- Back button and page title -->
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Button Content="Go Details" Command="{Binding DetailsCommand}" />

        </Grid>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                <!-- The entire page respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Padding">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="96,136,86,56"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

                <!--
                    The back button and title have different styles when snapped, and the list representation is substituted
                    for the grid displayed in all other view states
                -->
                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="itemGridView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
</common:LayoutAwarePage>
```

I can post for the second view but I don't think that's necessary.  Again, if I place a button in the view and set the Command binding to DetailsCommand, the second view pops up just fine.  Can't get it to work with item selection on the grid.

Comment: What you've done so far?

Comment: Just a wild guess, did you remember to implement your ICommand as a property?

Comment: Added some code to the question.  Hopefully that helps a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code, it seems you misunderstood the SelectedItem property of the ListView. It will be populated with one of your WorkListItem objects when the selection changes.

The ListView does not have a command property like the Button does, so you need to handle the SelectionChanged event of the ListView and invoke the Command on your Viewmodel manually.

You can do this in code-behind or take a look at one of the [EventToCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)  helpers to do it directly in xaml.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I'll have a look (I'm sure I did misunderstand the point).  Funny thing is, I have a stack of MSDN magazines here at my desk and couldn't find the article for April, May, or June of 2013 - perhaps an online thing only.  I'll post my results shortly...